# Pluck LIFO data emission from a stream from another observable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a stream of data coming in from an observable and I want to pull the trigger and capture the last emission and drop the rest. I basically want peek at the stream only when I click a button. Some things come close like skipWhile, combineLatest and the akarnokd's rxExtension library using valve and bufferWhile, but each fail in some way.

I only want to see the emissions from the stream when I press the button and it should be the last emitted. The data I want should also not wait on the stream to emit again and just give me the buffered last emission from that stream immediately when I press the button.

Also, that last emission grabbed should only be used once. If no data is emitted from the first stream after the last one is grabbed and used then subsequent triggers should not reuse that last emission.

Possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replay()` operator to capture the last item emitted, and `take(1)` to only look at the most recent item.

```
ConnectableObservable<String> srco = source.replay( 1 );
srco.connect();   // start the subscription
...
buttonClickObservable
  .flatMap( click -> srco
                       .take( 1 )
                       .last()
          )
  .subscribe( lastItem -> {},
              error -> { /* probably no item emitted */);
```

You may have to insert a tiny timeout to deal with the case of there being no emissions.